# cosmos db LINQ query in documentation

Tags: linq, azure-cosmosdb

I am reading the cosmos db documentation here
https://3c5.com/DQRpv

There are several examples which say something like this

```
input.Select(family => family.parents[0].familyName);
```

where the input is IQueryable of object.

My question is how do I get an IQueryable of object but ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like below:

```
Container container = await this.database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(containerId, "<partitionkeypath>");
var input = this.container.GetItemLinqQueryable<Family>();
input.Select(family => family.parents[0].familyName);
```

Where Family is the class defined to map with container properties.

Comment: Thanks Anurag for taking a peek at this. Wish Microsoft makes this explicit in their documentations so people like me don't feel overwhelmed :)